# Display Firestore map data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a password manager and I'm trying to save on Firestore reads by displaying data in Map. The idea is to have a document (for each password category) and have the passwords stored as maps in it. See example screenshots here:
[image]

The idea is that users click on each password (map) and the app takes them to the relevant one using indexes. I then want the data from each map to be sorted separately so that they can live in their own Text widgets. But I haven't seen any possibility of displaying map data in Flutter yet.

I've tried some of the examples from here but haven't been able to display the data from the map - https://github.com/fireship-io/flutter-base/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
new StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(userDocSTRING.toString())
        .collection(userPassSTRING.toString())
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        // If no data is present, display a waiting indicator to the user
        // If Null, red screen displays
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else {
        // Debug print for Ryan
        // print(snapshot.data[0].data.toString());
        return new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                snapshot.data.documents[index];
            return  ListTile(
                        leading: Container(
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.content_copy),
                              color: lightCardCOLOR,
                        title: Text(documentSnapshot['Name']
```

As you can see from the code above, fetching fields from documents is easy enough but I don't want each password to have it's own document. I want a document to hold multiple Maps which corresponds to a password. So `documentSnapshot['Name']` I want to be the name or value of a map

Comment: Please provide code examples of what exactly you already tried.

Comment: I've put my code in above and a brief summary at the end of what I want to accomplish

Comment: I'll suggest that your attempt to "save on Firestore reads" is making it more difficult for you to model and display the data.  It also won't scale, since the maximum size of a document is 1MB.  Consider storing each password in a different document to make this easier.  Document reads are not really very expensive, and the Firebase SDK will cache them locally to avoid the cost of reads when queried.

Comment: @DougStevenson I had completely forgotten about the 1MB limit - that would have cost me a lot of headaches seeing as this is a test platform for a much larger scale app! Can you post that response so that I can mark it as an answer? I will have to just cough up the price of the extra reads when it comes to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest that your attempt to "save on Firestore reads" is making it more difficult for you to model and display the data. It also won't scale, since the maximum size of a document is 1MB. Consider storing each password in a different document to make this easier. Document reads are not really very expensive, and the Firebase SDK will cache them locally to avoid the cost of reads when queried.